# Pandas - add value at specific iloc into new dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a large dataframe containing lots of columns.

For each row/index in the dataframe I do some operations, read in some ancilliary ata, etc and get a new value. Is there a way to add that new value into a new column at the correct row/index?

I can use .assign to add a new column but as I'm looping over the rows and only generating the data to add for one value at a time (generating it is quite involved). When it's generated I'd like to immediately add it to the dataframe rather than waiting until I've generated the entire series.

This doesn't work and gives a key error:

```
df['new_column_name'].iloc[this_row]=value
```

Do I need to initialise the column first or something?

Comment: It will be a lot easier to answer if you provide the operation you are trying to perform, a snippet of dataframe and the expected output.

Comment: The operation is quite complicated and involves reading and manipulating various datasets which ultimate results in one number being generated. I want to add that number into the correct row in my existing dataframe.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

There are two steps to created & populate a new column using only a row number...
(in this approach **iloc** is not used)

First, get the **row index** value by using the **row number**

```
rowIndex = df.index[someRowNumber]
```

Then, use **row index** with the **loc** function to reference the specific row and add the new column / value

```
df.loc[rowIndex, 'New Column Title'] = "some value"
```

These two steps can be combine into one line as follows

```
df.loc[df.index[someRowNumber], 'New Column Title'] = "some value"
```

Comment: Hey. I am using the steps you mentioned to add value in a particular row and column in a csv but it does not write in csv. Only the last row is written. Can you please revise this answer?

Comment: @sheharbano this question relates to pandas dataframes, not csv files. You could import the csv into a pandas dataframe, make the changes using instructions above, then write back to csv

Comment: Can this work on a specific set of scattered rowIndices, rather than just a single row at a time?

Answer (score 22):

If you have a dataframe like

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'X': [1.5, 6.777, 2.444, pd.np.NaN], 'Y': [1.111, pd.np.NaN, 8.77, pd.np.NaN], 'Z': [5.0, 2.333, 10, 6.6666]})
```

Instead of iloc,you can use `.loc` with row index and column name like `df.loc[row_indexer,column_indexer]=value`

```
df.loc[[0,3],'Z'] = 3
```

Output:

```
       X      Y       Z
0  1.500  1.111   3.000
1  6.777    NaN   2.333
2  2.444  8.770  10.000
3    NaN    NaN   3.000
```

Comment: This worked well for a problem I was having. Good solution

Comment: This only works because the index of the dataframe is the generic "counter" of row number. It won't work if you have named rows, e.g. using timestamps or simple strings. The [other solution from RumbleFish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47747369/3126298) is longer, but covers this case.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to add values to certain rows in a new column, depending on values in other cells of the dataframe you can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"A":[1,1,2,2], "B":[1,2,3,4]})
```

Add value in a new column based on the values in cloumn "A":

```
df.loc[df.A == 2, "C"] = 100
```

This creates the column "C" and addes the value 100 to it, if column "A" is 2.

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  1  NaN
1  1  2  NaN
2  2  3  100
3  2  4  100
```

It is not necessary to initialise the column first.

Comment: Works well! thanks

Comment: just one small correction, shouldn't it be `df.loc[df['A' ]== 2, "C"] = 100` ?

Comment: @LymanZerga Same, since `df.A == df['A']`

Answer (score 9):

You can just use pandas built in function DataFrame.at

You can chose a list on several index  or a single index and column

```
df.at[4, 'B'] = 10
```

Comment: This answer works perfect also when index is a datetime object, which does not yet exist in DataFrame. Thank you!